# updating sqlite database using a String not working

Tags: android, sqlite

This works but i need to be able to change the value of the product_name

```
String query = "UPDATE UserTable SET _quantity=_quantity - 1 WHERE product_name ='Hammer'";
myDatabase.execSQL(query);
```

This does not work and I can't see why.

```
String test = "Hammer";
String query = "UPDATE UserTable SET _quantity=_quantity - 1 WHERE product_name ='%"+test+ "%'";
myDatabase.execSQL(query);
```

Comment: try to remove % % symbol on your query!

Comment: the % symbol is to match anything like what he wants `%amme%` would match `hammer`

Comment: its just for testing that I have the String test set to Hammer.

Comment: Removing the % symbol did the trick, Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

i think it will work

```
ContentValues data = new ContentValues();
data.put("Column Name", column_value);
```

i.e,

```
data.put("_quantity", 3);

myDatabase.update(TABLE_NAME ,data,"product_name = ?",new String[]{test});
```

Answer (score 0):

To match a pattern you should use the LIKE statement:

```
String test = "Hammer";
String query = "UPDATE UserTable SET _quantity=_quantity - 1 WHERE product_name LIKE '%"+test+ "%'";
myDatabase.execSQL(query);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `%` symbols from your query. This symbols are used to match the strings values if you want to match anything like what he wants `%mer%` would match `hammer`

Try as below:

```
String query = "UPDATE UserTable SET _quantity=_quantity - 1 WHERE product_name ='"+test+ "'";
```